# Break-word property in letters

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-table, screen

Let's say I have this Table:

```
<Table>
<td>
<tr>Hello World</tr>
</td>
</table>
```

When I resize my browser to a mobile size, I want the text in my table to break down, so it fits in the width of the mobile browser.

For now only words break.. like:

On big screen:

```
Hello World
```

When screen gets too small to fit both words in one line:

```
Hello
World
```

But when the screen gets even smaller, the word will disappear over the right side of the screen. Instead I want it to break down like this when the screen gets too small to fit the word:

```
HE
LL
O

WO
RL
D
```

I tried the CSS property: `word-wrap: break-word;` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: your html is wrong, first comes <tr> and then <td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Grasper said, your html is wrong.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

This attribute is working for me in Chrome. CSS:

```
td {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: You were the first to post the `break-all` solution...

Answer (score 2):

You want the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Hello World and some other textthatmaynotbreak
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

table {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
td {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Use `word-break`, not `word-warp`.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/u8rwj/

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break-property

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with css when you aply

```
td{float:left}
```

Comment: Why float a table cell?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping a div around the text, then by changing the div's width, perhaps with some js, you can accomplish what you want.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UgBJL/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <td>
            <tr><div id="huh">Hello World</div></tr>
        </td>
    </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#huh{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width:2px;
}
```

Comment: This does not work as you shrink the width of the table, remove max-width and the table cell will remain a width just wide enough to enclose the whole words without breaking them.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>HelloWorldHelloWorld</td>
    </tr>
</table>

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
table td{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5kSwn/

Comment: @Mark: I saw your solution, word-break: break-all; which looks to be a good solution for this. Thanks:)

Comment: In your solution, using `table-layout: fixed` with `word-wrap: break-word` does the trick, so this works.  However, if `table-layout: auto`, then `word-wrap: break-word` will not work, but `word-break: break-all` will work.  So there are a couple of valid ways of getting the desired result.